# Get the parent object to use in dojo widget

Tags: json, dojo, widget

I am trying to parse the json  result object and use html template in a widget to display.

The json looks like this

```
 Result": [
{
    "Website": "Testing ",
    "Description": "Content from yahoo ",


    "LinkGroup": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "linkType": "information",
                "Link": {
                    "title": "Test1",
                    "url": "http://yahoo.com",
                    "description": "my Link Description"
                }
            },
            {
                "linkType": "news link",
                "Link": {
                    "title": "Test 2",
                    "url": "http://www.yahoo.com/news link...",
                    "description": "news link Link Description"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, 
{
    "Website": "Testing 2",
    "Description": "Content from google ",


    "LinkGroup": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "linkType": "information",
                "Link": {
                    "title": "Test1",
                    "url": "http://google.com",
                    "description": "my Link Description"
                }
            },
            {
                "linkType": "news link",
                "Link": {
                    "title": "Test 2",
                    "url": "http://www.google.com/news link...",
                    "description": "news link Link Description"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

I was earlier able to parse just the entry items and used it on a templated widget. I would now like to use the Website and Description object within my widget. Instead of the entry array object I tried to parse the Result object and tried to access the entry. Looking at the console log I see it stops when it tries to get the entry value. I am wondering how to parse it so I can first get the website and description and then add the entry items within that.
This is my html widget code

```
                 <div><span title="${Link.description}">${Link.description</span>/div> <br />
              <a href="${Link.url}">${Link.title}</a><br />
```

and I parse the json with this code

```
                 request("js/my/data/sample.json", {
                handleAs: "json"}).then(function(jsonResults){ 
                arrayUtil.forEach(jsonResults.LinksGroup, function(List) 
              {arrayUtil.forEach(List.LinksGroup.entry, function(Ientry){
               var widget = new support(Ientry).placeAt(authorContainer);

               });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I used another widget within the array before the entry object which did the trick.